# wrapper function with es6 import without needing a variable name (for React higher order component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using commonjs require, I can do this -

```
let wrapper = require('./wrapper')
let Nephi = wrapper(require('./Nephi'))
```

Use es6 import syntax, it seems I have to do this -

```
import wrapper from './wrapper'
import Nephi from './Nephi'
let Nephi2 = wrapper(Nephi)
```

I tried this below:

```
import wrapper from './wrapper'
import Nephi from './Nephi'
Nephi = wrapper(Nephi)
```

but I get a 'read-only' error.  Am I stuck with having to use another variable name if I use 'import'?

Comment: You don't need to call the import variable name the name of the package. So you could do something like `import _Nephi from './Nephi'; let Nephi = wrapper(Nephi);`

Comment: @adam-beck if that's the case, it sounds like I am stuck having to use another variable name ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.  Bummer.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I think `import` does some strange things with hoisting and throwing Syntax errors which is why you can't just re-assign the variable afterwards. I also don't think the answer by @Suren Srapyan will work. Think being the key word there.

Comment: Imported variables are like `const`, you can't assign to them.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @loganfsmyth -

> Imported variables are like const, you can't assign to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
import { wrapper } from './wrapper'
import { Nephi } from './Nephi'
Nephi = wrapper(Nephi)
```

If you use without `{}`, it means that you need to export `as default`

Comment: Aren't you assuming that Nephi is exported as a standalone object with this? Meaning that its authored as `module.exports.Nephi = {}` and not necessarily just `module.exports = {}`.

Comment: Maybe. So I suggest him to try to use

Answer (score 0):

why not import the wrapper inside Nephi, then export a wrapped Nephi object?

`export default wrapper(Nephi);`

or

`import Nephi as unwrappedNephi from './Nephi';`

`const Nephi = wrapper(unwrappedNephi);`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to wrap the exported object because I may want to pass some options to the wrapper that will be different for each instance.  On the 2nd option I think the syntax isn't right.  Did you mean for it to be `import Nephi, * as unwrappedNephi from './Nephi';`?  Even with that I still get a `Duplicate declaration "Nephi"` error by using `const Nephi = ...` after the `import Nephi ...`.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to wrap on curly braces the member you want to import, on the wrapper.js and Nephi.js, you have to export them as default. e.g.

inside wrapper.js

```
export default function wrapper(ob) { ... }
```

inside Nephi.js

```
export default Nephi = { ... };
```

import them like:

```
import wrapper from './wrapper';
import Nephi from './Nephi';
var nephi2 = wrapper(Nephi);
```